# Using a python2 library with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, ip

I'm using python3 and geolite2, but I'm finding that I cannot pass in the IP address that I want to look up and I get the following error. I have tried converting to utf-8 and encoding, but am getting the same error.

```
from geoip import geolite2

ip_address = request.access_route[0] or request.remote_addr
print(">>>", ip_address)
ip_bytes = ip_address.encode('utf-8')
loc = geolite2.lookup(ip_bytes)
```

or

```
loc = geolite2.lookup(ip_address.encode())
```

Following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

What format should the IP go in as. In the original doc, it is `string`.

http://pythonhosted.org/python-geoip/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the official [Python geoip2 API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoip2) or [python-geoip-yplan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-geoip-yplan/). The latter is a fork of python-geoip with better Python 3 support.